# How to create an empty plot in rCharts?

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I'm trying to add an rCharts output to a shiny app. If the inputs are not valid, then I don't want to output anything - so I'd like to be able to just return `NULL` or somehow have an "empty plot" in the output.  But I can't figure out how to create an empty plot in rCharts.

Here's the code I have, the example is taken straight out of the README but I commented out the plot code and returned NULL instead

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Interactive Charts from R using polychart.js"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
                label = "Choose X",
                choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                selected = "SepalLength"),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
                label = "Choose Y",
                choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                selected = "SepalWidth")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "polycharts")
  )
)

server<- function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    # names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))
    # p1 <- rPlot(input$x, input$y, data = iris, color = "Species", 
    #             facet = "Species", type = 'point')
    # p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
    # return(p1)
    return(NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showOutput` expects an object back right, so why do you give back an empty object of that class.

```
output$myChart <- renderChart({
        mychart <- Polycharts$new()
        return(mychart)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a complete noob with rCharts, that's exactly what I needed to know how to do. Thanks. I saw a different answer that said I should use `renderChart2` instead - do you happen to know the difference?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest when to use one or the other, I think there is a dependence on some of the libraries that it has to return an object so he introduced a patch with `renderChart2` to cover that but again Im not 100% sure. The main difference is what libs are u using such as `polycharts`, `nvd3`, `highcharts` or others